# i can't Resolve this 'Force finishing Activity or FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher'

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my code:

```
OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
         override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                val body1  = "{\"contents\":["+body+"]}"
                println(body1)
                val con = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(body1, Con::class.java)
                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView3.adapter= ChapterActivity.ChapterAdapter(con)
```

i want to fetch json in Con class:

```
class Con(val cont:List<contents>)
class contents(val content:String,val thumb:String)
```

error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/*******/******/Con;
```

Comment: If you're getting this at deserialization line (gson) it may be because of absence of default constructor for your classes.

Comment: but this perfectly work in it's parent Activity.

Comment: Could you please provide full stack trace?